# clases duplicadas en android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Tengo el siguiente código, que convierte coordenadas en formato Lat, Long a UTM:

```
import static org.jscience.geography.coordinates.crs.ReferenceEllipsoid.WGS84;
import org.jscience.geography.coordinates.*;
import javax.measure.unit.NonSI;

Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(AfegirccActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses= null;
addresses =     geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
double latitud = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
double longitud = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
LatLong latLong = LatLong.valueOf(latitud, longitud, NonSI.DEGREE_ANGLE);
UTM utm = UTM.latLongToUtm(latLong, WGS84);
```

el problema lo tengo en las dependencias que al hacer build sale que hay clases duplicadas:

```
Duplicate class javolution.ContextTestSuite$ArrayAllocation found in modules jetified-javolution-5.2.3 (org.javolution:javolution:5.2.3) and jetified-jscience-4.3.1 (org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1)
```

las dependencias que tengo son las siguientes:

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1' // Location API
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1' // JScience library for units of measurement (https://jscience.org/)
```

}

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules
> kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and
> xmlpull-1.1.3.4d_b4_min.jar (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min)

indica que tienes clases duplicadas en las dependencias que definiste en tu proyecto, para evitar este problema, puedes excluir las clases repetidas, define dentro de tu archivo `app/build.gradle` una exclusión de clases:

```
 android{
   ...    
   ...
   ...        
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'javolution', module: 'javolution'             
        }

    }
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no parece que haga algo